# Resident Card stolen can I still travel in Schengen?

Tags: schengen, poland, czech-republic

My friend is a student in Poland and have valid Temporary Resident Card (Karta Pobytu). His purse was stolen which had his resident card. He has already obtained a Police Report and Reported to the resident card issuing authorities (to get the replacement). They have given him certificate for the same. However, it will take almost a month to get the replacement. Now, he want me to visit me in Prague for next week. Can he come to Prague with this temporary certificate and passport? He is planning to come by FlixBus.

Comment: What is your friend's citizenship?

Comment: Was his passport also stolen?

Comment: The second-to-last sentence of the question suggests that the friend still has his passport.

Comment: One of my friend has faced similar situation who is working in Warsaw. With temporary certificate, you can not cross international border. It only tells you that you are staying in Poland legally. My friend had ask this question in the immigration office in Warsaw and they only told that with this certificate, you can not travel outside Poland.